# Angular 6 search functionality

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient

I am trying to make a search function to return an observable object array for matches for the search term in Angular 6, against more than one property of the object.
My object currently has 3 properties, and using http client, I can search only one property. 
Object.name or object.id. I got this far modifying the heroes tour tutorial on the angular website. To relate my objective to the heroes tutorial, i want to search for a hero by id,name, and eventually by other properties. 
I currently have 3 string arrays each with the object name, id, and another property. I also made a function that creates an object array by joining the string arrays.
I don't know if this is even the best way to go about doing this task, I am originally working with an excel sheet and trying to build a mock database with its data. I have been told to make the data into a json file, and keep it in my asset folder.

```
searchPaints(term: string): Observable<Paint[]> {
    if (!term.trim()) {
      // if not search term, return empty paint array.
      return of([]);
    }
   return this.http.get<Paint[]>(`${this.paintsUrl}/?name=${term}`)

   .pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`found paints matching "${term}"`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Paint[]>('searchPaints', []))
    );
  }
```

this is an example of the code, I can modify the get request to

```
this.http.get<Paint[]>(`${this.paintsUrl}/?id=${term}`)
```

and i am able to get results by ID, but the paint object, will eventually have many other properties.

I want it to function that if i search by any property, it will do the search in each property of paint, and return combined results.

I have been exploring forkjoin, but i haven't gotten anything functional so far.

Comment: I think it would help if you could give us some sample code! In general, I think you just send one search term, and then do an or search on the object itself. Unless you are hoping for 3 different text fields to search for each object property specifically? Again, a bit of sample code can help us answer your question easier!

Comment: edited to contain code

Answer (score 0):

The way I have generally handled this stuff in the past is with an OR query in the database. Not sure if thats not an option for some reason?

I would make the query:
this.http.get(`${this.paintsUrl}/?query=${term}`)

Not sure what database you are using.
SQL

```
SELECT * FROM Paint WHERE Id LIKE '%@query%' OR Color LIKE '%@query%'
```

Mongo

```
{ $or: [ { "Id": /.*query.*/i }, { "Color": /.*query.*/i } ] }
```